# EMC PowerPath Support Matrix

Tags: storage, emc, powerpath

I know this is a stupid question, but I've found nothing online.  Does anyone know where EMC has hidden the support matrix documentation so that I know what version of PowerPath is supported with which version of FLARE?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you already checked, but EMC's Powerlink is where you should check at the first place.

http://powerlink.emc.com/

There you can find all sort of infos about it, and all others EMC's products.

Comment: Try to provide explanation too,links might be not available after some time.

Comment: I spent hours looking through Powerlink before I posted this question and wasn't able to find anything.

Comment: There is also the https://elabnavigator.emc.com/eln/hostConnectivity that you can access thru the PowerLink. Have you also looked at there? Cause I could find the a list with several versions, and the Storage OS that are compatible... (https://elabnavigator.emc.com/eln/components?26/2/73907/71952/64569)